# tomcat/Liferay is not redirecting to https theme and hook

Tags: tomcat, nginx, liferay, liferay-6

I have changed the server, hence I'm pointing from nginx to newipserver:8080

The issue is that all the related links of Liferay themes and hook are pointing to `http` not to `https` and the themes are not working. I've changed this configuration in `server.xml` to , but doesn't work.

```
<Connector
    URIEncoding="UTF-8"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    proxyPort="80"
    proxyName="www.domain1.com"
    port="8080"
    protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    redirectPort="443"
    maxHttpHeaderSize="99999"
    enableLookups="false" />
    <Connector
        port="443"
        protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        enableLookups="false"
        redirectPort="8443" />
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What links are you talking about? If you explicitly link to http in web content and theme-templates - that's what Liferay displays.

Comment: change http:// to // for all css and js files you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your dilemma is described in the following blog post:

https://www.liferay.com/web/kamesh.sampath/blog/-/blogs/nginx-ssl-load-balancing-with-liferay

In summary, SSL terminates at NGINX and NGINX is not communicating that the request was originally HTTPS to the application server; rather, it's telling the application server that it's an HTTP request.

Since the application server is being told that it's an HTTP request, it tells Liferay the same thing. Therefore, all requests are assumed to be HTTP rather than HTTPS, and since Liferay isn't generating protocol-relative URLs, you experience the problem you've described.

As mentioned in the blog post, assuming you do not need to access the application server directly (you are comfortable with having all requests reach it through NGINX), you can set the `secure` attribute to `true` on your Connector as described in the Tomcat documentation.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes

If you do need to access the server directly, you will need to add another Connector on a different port where the `secure` flag is `false`.